# Tables No Longer Appear in Connections List - Azure Data Studio 1.41, Azure SQL Server Database

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-data-studio

Specifically for my connection to an Azure SQL Server Database after upgrading to Azure Data Studio v1.41.

When I connect into my Server/Database, and expand the Tables section from the left side menu, none of my tables appear. (Also my Views and Stored Procedures are not visible.)

They do still exist. They appear when the Manage option is selected, and I can access the data.

This means I am without access to Table Design for existing tables and other quick actions that would appear there.

Please help, it was all there when I had v1.40 installed earlier!

I have tried to log in using different accounts (server admin, Azure AD and another user account), none of which showed the tables under server connection. I have also restarted, refreshed and tried the Insider v1.42 build, all with the same outcome.

Comment: I had literally just upgraded this morning, and [can replicate the behaviour](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoYAs.png) against an Azure SQL Database. It doesn't occur against any of our on-premises instances. I would suggest logging a bug on their GitHub, if I am honest.

Comment: I've gone ahead and [logged an issue](https://github.com/microsoft/azuredatastudio/issues/21735).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest release of Azure Data Studio 1.41.1:

> ### [Bug fixes in 1.41.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/sql/azure-data-studio/release-notes-azure-data-studio?view=sql-server-ver16#bug-fixes-in-1411)
>
> | New Item | Details |
> | --- | --- |
> | Connection | Fixed a bug causing incorrect Azure account tenant selection when connecting to server through the Azure view. |
> | Object Explorer | Fixed a regression which caused Object Explorer to not show database objects for Azure SQL DB Basic SLO. |

I can confirmed, as well, that the regression no longer occurs:
[image]